# Error during creation of VM with Xen

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, xen

So, I've been following this tutorial: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Xen to help me create a virtual machine using the Xen software installed in Ubuntu 16.04. I have managed to install Xen hypervisor without problems, and have created the virtual volume to install the VM, all according to the tutorial.

But in the section of the tutorial "Manually Create a PV Guest VM", I am supposed to modify a document called "ubud1.cfg" and paste some lines into this document. After I have this done, I'm supposed to install the VM through the terminal with the command:

```
sudo xl create -c /etc/xen/ubud1.cfg
```

but this does not work. It produces the error messages

Parsing config from /etc/xen/ubud1.cfg
libxl: error: libxl_exec.c:118:libxl_report_child_exitstatus: /etc/xen/scripts/vif-openvswitch online [6473] exited with error status 1
libxl: error: libxl_device.c:1138:device_hotplug_child_death_cb: script: Unable to find ovs-vsctl tool
libxl: error: libxl_create.c:1384:domcreate_attach_vtpms: unable to add nic devices
libxl: error: libxl.c:1610:libxl__destroy_domid: non-existant domain 6
libxl: error: libxl.c:1568:domain_destroy_callback: unable to destroy guest with domid 6
libxl: error: libxl.c:1495:domain_destroy_cb: destruction of domain 6 failed

And I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I have followed the tutorial and done everything according to it at this point, but I feel like I've missed something. I am not very knowledgeable in Ubuntu and I don't know what this error message produced in the terminal is supposed to mean, that's why I've come here for help.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Did you use the bridge-utils network bridging earlier in the tutorial and not openvswitch-switch? If so, comment out this line in the ubud1.cfg file.

`# Custom option for Open vSwitch
vif = [ 'script=vif-openvswitch,bridge=ovsbr0' ]`

It let the new VM start up, but I've apparently configured bridge-utils wrong so I don't have a network interface yet. Good luck.